# Migrating GWT 1.7 to GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

I am trying to upgrade GWT from 1.7 to GWT 2.4 but I get build errors saying

Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/src/project/lib/gxt.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/Component.java'
[ERROR] Line 1280: Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Widget

Should I change the gxt version as well? I tried to change gxt to 2.2.5 and 2.2.6 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need to upgrade GXT. GXT 2.2.4+ should work. Check the release notes; they say GWT 2.3 support is introduced in GXT version 2.2.4.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.4/release_notes.html#Release_2.2.4

They also answer this in the forums.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146796-GWT-2.4-compatibility

Comment: May be you are wrong, this class `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Events` does not exist in gxt 2.2.4

Comment: I checked the jar, they are extjs, for gxt 3, they are com.sencha